# How would one 3d plot the CDF of a probability mass function in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I have attempted to plot the Cumulative Distribution Function of a simple piecewise probability mass function, but the code:

```
Plot3D[CDF[p[x, y], {x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

where p[x_, y_] is the function Piecewise[...]. This yields an empty plot - why is this so? Do I have to make p of probability distribution type?

Comment: Please provide a minimal non-working example of `p[x,y]`

Comment: The first argument of `CDF` should be a **distribution** rather than a probability mass function or probability density function. To convert a pdf to a distribution see [`ProbabilityDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon yes I realized that the ProbabilityDistribution function takes in  Probability Density Function as parameter, but since I do not have the PDF and only the have the probability mass distribution on an x-y plane, I was wondering whether it would be possible to get the CDF from this?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `ProbabilityDistribution` again. It will take your pmf/pdf (`p[x, y]`) and assumptions/constraints as inputs and define the distribution that can be used as an input to `CDF`

Comment: Thanks for the response @BobHanlon even from reading the documentation it is still not apparent to me that the ProbabilityDistribution function takes pmf ? Would you mind pointing out where exactly this information is?

Comment: From the documentation for `PDF`, "For discrete distributions, PDF is also known as a probability mass function."

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
```

You have a user-defined pmf (pdf in Mathematica terms), `p[x, y]`, For example,

```
p[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{
    {1/8, x == 0 && y == 0},
    {1/4, x == 0 && y == 1},
    {1/4, x == 1 && y == 0},
    {3/8, x == 1 && y == 1}}];
```

[`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html) is used to define the associated distribution

[image]

```
distXY = ProbabilityDistribution[p[x, y], {x, 0, 1, 1}, {y, 0, 1, 1}];
```

The distribution is used to define the [`CDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDF.html)

```
CDF[distXY, {x, y}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[CDF[distXY, {x, y}], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 2}]
```

[image]